# Diodes needed (parts) for OR gate automotive relay circuit

Tags: relay, logic-gates, automotive, 12v

I need to power up a make-or-break simple automotive relay (4pin, 40A 12V) via an OR gate.

OR gate as follows:

- Source 1 is the cable that provides +12V to activate car dome light which I will tap into and
- source 2 is engine-on port from the busbar, obviously +12V when engine is on.

So if the dome light is on OR if the engine is on, the relay will activate.

I understand I
   need to put one way diodes on both my sources and connect them to pin
   85 of the relay.  What type of diodes I need to purchase?

*EDIT*  automotive relays have standardized pin numbers ie in this case a 4 pin relay has pins 30, 85, 86, 87

Comment: A four pin relay, and you want to connect to pin 85?  Something is missing.

Comment: What is pin 85?

Comment: @Hearth  Automotive pin numbering is standardized. See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_72552)

Comment: @mike65535 That's information that should be included in the question, probably, since it seems both I and JRE are unfamiliar with it, at least.

Comment: Only be carefull because in some automotive relays there is a flyback diode in parallel to the coil (between 85 and 86 pins).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face is the dome light is usually switched on the ground side, via the door contacts. The engine-on is switched on the battery plus side in contrary. You cannot simply diode-or this circuit because you don't have a common potential.

You need a helper relay to overcome that problem. The diode must be rated for the coil current of the power relay. A 1N4001 should be sufficient.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK3r2A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I wasn't clear:  The dome light is activated by a +12v +ve cable which I will tap into, so no negative.  I will also tap into an engine on port in the busbar, so both my OR inputs will be positive.  Plan to use a standard vw 4 port relay (ports 30, 85,86,87)
Many thanks!